# Django Form unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

i have a form which contains a choiceField and i need to populate it from a view, so i'm trying to use the kwargs inside the init function like this :

```py
class SelectionFournisseur(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectionFournisseur, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Fournisseur'].choices = kwargs.pop("choixF",None)
    
    Fournisseur = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ())
```

my view :

```
formF = SelectionFournisseur(choixF=choices)
```

but i get the error `BaseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choixF'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the extra argument before calling `super` and afterwards use the stored argument

```
class SelectionFournisseur(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._choixF = kwargs.pop('choixF', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Fournisseur'].choices = self._choixF
```

Now your extra argument does not interfere with the `super().__init__` call.